# Tizen Emulator not starting on windows 10 via emulator manager of tizen studio

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

I have recently installed Tizen Studio 1.1.0 and than installed tizen-sdk, tizen 3.0 and 2.4 OS version for mobile development.

Two emulator for Tizen3.0 and 2.4 is came created with all installation process.

Just created new TAUUIComponent Sample project.
I wants to launch that on Emulator but emulator is not starting.

**When click on launch button of emulator manager, It show circular progress for 2 second and than nothing happens, No any error or warning dialog displayed.**
How to resolve this problem and start emulator ?

Extra: I have tried "Right click on project -> Run as -> tizen web simulator application" and its working fine.

Updated Hint:
After long time i have updated packages via package manager.
Now, I found emulator's status is empty but when i hover mouse on status column it shows popup message "Platform image not accessible"

Comment: Check my answer here.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59049468/tizen-studio-emulator-and-device-manager-not-working/60448516#60448516

Answer (score 1):

Let me share my experience.
I was using windows 10, tizen studio 3.6
Emulator and device manager not worked.
I tried several times. finally I've solved.
I tested jdk12, jdk 13 for tizen studio.
This was the reason.
I contacted samsung developer support and they said, I have to install Oracle Jdk 8.
I installed JDK 8, and now everything is working well.
Hope to help everyone who has trobule with emulator manager.

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable Hyper-V Manager

Comment: how can i disable Hyper-V Manager ? I have no idea on that.

Comment: you can go Control Panel and at your left hand side ,click "Turn Windows Features on or off " > disable Hyper-V Manager

Comment: I have checked, Hyper-V Manager is already disabled. still emulator is not working.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to find where the emulator stores its logs. Most probably in a directory called something like tizen-studio-data (this is the case on OSX). From the logs you can address the issue and look for a specific solution avoiding trial/error cycle. In many cases the issue is related to HAXM, the virtualization engine the emulator is based on. Basically you need to install specific drivers from the Intel website to make it work on your machine.