# Tizen Studio Emulator and Device Manager not working

Tags: tizen, samsung-smart-tv, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-studio

Working in Tizen studio for Samsung tv apps. Emulator and Device manager continuously give me an error. I am unable to open that from IDE. My app is working fine on emulator but getting error while running on Samsung TV using Samsung certificate.

The error I'm getting is this:

> The application was unable to start correctly (0xc000007b). Click OK to close the application.

Please help me to resolve this error. I am new and got stuck in Tizen Studio

[image]

Comment: Most problems with tools from TizenStudio are caused by incorrect java environment. Please verify that You have installed the same versions as provided here: https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/tizen-studio/download/prerequisites?langredirect=1 or openJDK (https://developer.tizen.org/ko/development/articles/openjdk-and-openjfx-installation-guide?langredirect=1)

Answer (score 3):

I contacted with samsung developer support.
They said, I have to install jdk8
I did so, and now it is working.
Before, I installed jdk13, jdk12, and all was not working.
but now it is working after installed jdk8.

Answer (score 1):

I was able to avoid these errors by running Tizen Studio as an administrator.